singer tap is returning STATE objects instead of RECORD
I am trying to run a google ads tap on singer-io to get data from the GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT stream. However, when I run the tap with the appropriate config.json and catalog.json file, the output I get contains STATE objects instead of getting RECORDs. The state itself is not null, which presumably means that it does recognize data for the stream.
config.json (I had to add both customer_ids and login_customer_ids otherwise I was getting an error):
{
    "developer_token": "<developer_token>",
    "oauth_client_id": "<oauth_client_id>",
    "oauth_client_secret": "<oauth_client_secret>",
    "refresh_token": "<refresh_token>",
    "start_date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "end_date": "2020-10-06T00:00:00Z",
    "customer_ids": [
        {
            "customerId": "<customerId>",
            "loginCustomerId": "<loginCustomerId>"
        }
    ],
    "login_customer_ids": [
        {
            "customerId": "<customerId>",
            "loginCustomerId": "<loginCustomerId>"
        }
    ]
}

My catalog file does have "selected": true for all the required streams in the right places. Again, singer is recognizing the data. Just not outputting it.
target.json (ouputting the tap results here):
{
    "type": "SCHEMA",
    "stream": "geo_performance_report",
    "schema": {
        [...]
    },
    "key_properties": [
        "_sdc_record_hash"
    ]
}
{
    "type": "STATE",
    "value": {
        "currently_syncing": [
            "geo_performance_report",
            "<customerId>"
        ]
    }
}
{
    "type": "STATE",
    "value": {
        "currently_syncing": [
            "geo_performance_report",
            "<customerId>"
        ],
        "bookmarks": {
            "geo_performance_report": {
                "<customerId>": {
                    "date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00.000000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "type": "STATE",
    "value": {
        "currently_syncing": [
            "geo_performance_report",
            "<customerId>"
        ],
        "bookmarks": {
            "geo_performance_report": {
                "<customerId>": {
                    "date": "2020-10-02T00:00:00.000000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "type": "STATE",
    "value": {
        "currently_syncing": [
            "geo_performance_report",
            "<customerId>"
        ],
        "bookmarks": {
            "geo_performance_report": {
                "<customerId>": {
                    "date": "2020-10-03T00:00:00.000000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[...]

I am unsure how to fix this issue. There seems to be no documentation or forum on such an issue.
